# How can I catch the event that happens only when the value of a <select> changes through user input?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code for a normal select list:

```
   $('.update-title')
        .change(function () {
            var title = $('option:selected', this).prop('title');
             $("#modal_Title").val(title);
        });
```

This seems to be getting triggered when the select is populated. Is there I can make this happen ONLY when a user goes in and manually reselects a different value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `change` event is only triggered by the browser when the element gains focus, the value changes, and the element loses focus. That doesn't happen when the element is initially populated, and I've never personally come across the `change` event being triggered when the `<select>` is initially populated.

It seems that you have some code somewhere that is programmatically triggering the change event handler on that element, because what you're describing isn't standard behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a Boolean value to determine if the event is triggered for the first time. For example, your code can be something like this...

```
var first_time_select = true;
$('.update-title')
    .change(function () {
        if (first_time_select) {
            first_time_select = false;
        } else {
            var title = $('option:selected', this).prop('title');
            $("#modal_Title").val(title);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fully correct,except the syntax error. remove the syntax error

working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CXkt4/1/)**

```
$('.update-title')
        .change(function () {
            var title = $('option:selected', this).prop('title');
             $("#modal_Title").val(title);//you are missing quotes
        });
```

Comment: You are correct about the error, but it's not a solution to his problem. Should be a comment.

Comment: @sibu - It was my error with typing into Stackoverflow. The above code you gave still has the same problem as in the question. Anders - thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Marilou can you post code how your select is getting populated

Comment: @Sorry about this. Anthony was correct. There is an event fired that does a change and that's causing the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not as such, but you can always assign data to the select box when you change it programmatically. Then you'd check if it's set on change:

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
    $('.update-title').data('dont-change', 1);
    // repopulate the dropdown here...
});

$('.update-title')
    .change(function () {
        if (!$(this).data('dont-change')) {
            var title = $('option:selected', this).prop('title');
             $("#modal_Title").val(title);//you are missing quotes
        } else {
            $(this).removeData('dont-change');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about exactly why your select's change event is getting triggered when you populate it with data (I've noticed something like this happening with Knockout for me). However, if you want to avoid it getting triggered, why not use `.off()` ([link](http://api.jquery.com/off/)) on the element when you are changing it, and then `.on(callback)` to activate it again? (I would recommend doing this with a named function instead of an inline one.)

Here is a contrived example: http://jsfiddle.net/b2x2T/11/

Note that in that example I wouldn't actually need to use on/off as it won't trigger the `change` event, but I think you get the idea.

Edit: Out of curiosity, when and how are you populating the select list?

Comment: My huge mistake. I found code doing sending a change trigger. Thanks so much for your advice.

Comment: That's good to hear - usually it's ourselves and not the code that's doing something wrong... :)